# Are religious education shopping questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

This site seems to be allowing denominational "shopping" questions of the general form "Are there any denominations that have/support/allow/require X?" For example, see:

- [Does any church still provide a pension for widows?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26755/does-any-church-still-provide-a-pension-for-widows)
- [Does any church follow the Apostolic Tradition of Baptism ‘in the nude’, or was that never the tradition?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8526/does-any-church-follow-the-apostolic-tradition-of-baptism-in-the-nude-or-was)
- [Do any groups of Quakers still disapprove of the fine arts?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45329/do-any-groups-of-quakers-still-disapprove-of-the-fine-arts)
- [Are there any groups of Christians who believe that all loans made with their money should be made without the expectation of repayment?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45609/are-there-any-groups-of-christians-who-believe-that-all-loans-made-with-their-mo)
- [Is there a group of Christians that believes that Jesus was resurrected metaphorically rather than physically?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11983/is-there-a-group-of-christians-that-believes-that-jesus-was-resurrected-metaphor)
- [Are there any Christian groups that follow Matthew 23:9?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/are-there-any-christian-groups-that-follow-matthew-239)
- [What Christian groups believe sex was the original sin, and not disobedience?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/what-christian-groups-believe-sex-was-the-original-sin-and-not-disobedience)

Are similar questions about religious education providers allowed? These might be of the form "Are there any seminaries/bible schools/bible colleges/Sunday school curriculum providers/missionary preparation programs/catechical classes/etc. that have/support/allow/require/etc. X?"

Example questions:

- Are there any bible schools where I can earn a degree in History of Bible Translation?
- Are there any formal published Sunday School curricula that specifically discuss the influence of Gnosticism on early Christian spirituality?
- Is there a Lutheran seminary in Hokkaido?
- Is there anywhere I can take an online, self-paced course in systematic theology from a Reformed perspective and receive college credit?
- I have been serving as a Lay Minister for many years and have learned a great deal of formal theology and discipleship concepts. Are there any seminaries which will grant me advanced status toward a Master of Divinity degree if I present a portfolio/pass an exam/etc.?

If these kinds of questions are allowed with limitations, what are those limitations?

Answer (score 1):

The denominational "shopping" questions that we allow could really be called denomination "surveys" - questions designed to identify the denominations (or some other Christian categorisation) that fit a certain set of beliefs or practices. They are not however intended to identify specific local or geographical organisations which fit those criteria.

The sample questions you have listed there are much more pure shopping questions, and should not be accepted on this site.